# No output from subscriber

Tags: c++, ros

This is a part of the subscriber code. I would like to print out ytmp in the callback, but nothing was being printed, not even once. No idea what is wrong with my code here. It does print out ytmp inside the while(ros::ok()). Why did it skip the callback ??

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/Vector3.h>
double ytmp,ztmp;

void SubCallback(const geometry_msgs::Vector3::ConstPtr& msg)
{
   //ROS_INFO("I heard: [%f]", msg->y);
   //ROS_INFO("I heard: [%f]", msg->z);   
   ytmp = msg->y; 
   ztmp = msg->z;
   std::cout<<"ytmp CALLBACK = "<<ytmp<<std::endl;
}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{


   ros::init(argc, argv, "basic_shapes");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   ros::Rate r(1);
   ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("intersect_values", 1000, SubCallback);
   ros::Publisher marker_pub = n.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("visualization_marker", 10);

   // Set our initial shape type to be a cube
   uint32_t shape = visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE;

   while (ros::ok())
   {
     std::cout<<"abc = "<<ytmp<<std::endl;
     visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
     // Set the frame ID and timestamp.  See the TF tutorials for information on these.
     marker.header.frame_id = "world";
     marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

     // Set the namespace and id for this marker.  This serves to create a unique ID
     // Any marker sent with the same namespace and id will overwrite the old one
     marker.ns = "basic_shapes";
     marker.id = 0;

     // Set the marker type.  Initially this is CUBE, and cycles between that and SPHERE, ARROW, and CYLINDER
     // Set the marker action.  Options are ADD, DELETE, and new in ROS Indigo: 3 (DELETEALL)
     marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;

     // Set the pose of the marker.  This is a full 6DOF pose relative to the frame/time specified in the header
     marker.pose.position.x = 0;// rwr_x;// joint1_x;        // 2.52782791;
     marker.pose.position.y = ytmp;//cord_y;// rwr_y;//joint1_y;        //0.0182385;

     std::cout<<"ytmp = "<<ytmp<<std::endl;         

     marker.pose.position.z = ztmp;//cord_z;// rwr_z;//joint1_z;        //0;
     marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
     marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
     marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
     marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

     // Set the scale of the marker -- 1x1x1 here means 1m on a side
     marker.scale.x = 0.2;
     marker.scale.y = 0.2;
     marker.scale.z = 0.2;

     // Set the color -- be sure to set alpha to something non-zero!
     marker.color.r = 1.0f;
     marker.color.g = 1.0f;
     marker.color.b = 0.0f;
     marker.color.a = 2.0;

     marker.lifetime = ros::Duration();

     // Publish the marker
    /* while (marker_pub.getNumSubscribers() < 1)
     {
    //std::cout << "marker_pub.getNumSubscribers() = " <<    marker_pub.getNumSubscribers() << std::endl;
       if (!ros::ok())
       {
     return 0;
       }
       ROS_WARN_ONCE("Please create a subscriber to the marker");
       //sleep(1);
       }*/
       marker_pub.publish(marker);
       r.sleep();
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to call ros::spin in your subscriber in order to pump callbacks? Why are your publisher and subscriber running on the same thread anyway?

Comment: yes.. the problem is missing `ros::spinOnce();` !! I want it to subscribe to a topic called intersect_values to grab  a set of values and assign the values to print it out as marker.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking in your comment. In addition, I don't really have any knowledge of the ros framework, simply made that observation based on their basic examples.

Comment: Create a [MCVE]